# Javascript / Webix referencing objects as arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, webix

This is primarily a Javascript / JSON question, however if anyone knows of a Webix solution, I'm open to that as well.

**Background**

I'm using [Webix](https://webix.com/) as a Javascript UI framework.  Currently I'm populating a [Webix Datatable](https://docs.webix.com/datatable__index.html) with JSON data that looks something like this:

```
complexData = {
  "metadata": {
    "itemno": 111222333,
    "groupid": 19,
    "name": "Blah"
  },
  "configs": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "First",
      "description": "some stuff",
      "value": 222
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Third",
      "description": "Foo",
      "value": 333
    }
  ],
  "system": null
}
```

I'm init'ing my Datatable component, like this:

```
webix.ui({
    view:"datatable",
    columns:[
        { id:"id", header:"ID" },
        { id:"name", header:"Name" },        
        { id:"description", header:"Description", fillspace: true },
        { id:"value", header:"Value" }
    ],
    data: complexData.configs
});
```

Which works great.

You can see what that looks like here:  https://snippet.webix.com/4jd9cobb.

As you can see, I'm just 'reaching into' `complexData` and referencing `configs`, to get the data for my component.

However, (due to processing I need to do later), I need to change my data-structure slightly.  I need the objects within `configs` to be keyed based on their `id`, which can be arbitrary.  This, of course, means that `configs` is now an object of objects, not just an array:

```
complexData = {
  "metadata": {
    "itemid": 111222333,
    "groupid": 19,
    "name": "Blah"
  },
  "configs": {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "First",
      "description": "some stuff",
      "value": 222
    },
    "3": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Third",
      "description": "Foo",
      "value": 333
    }
    },
  "system": null
}
```

This no longer renders my rows.

Here's what this looks like: https://snippet.webix.com/n8ypdeia

**Details**

If I `console.log` my working result (the array), I get this:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
  0: {id: 1, name: "First", description: "some stuff", value: 222 }
  1: {id: 3, name: "Third", description: "Foo", value: 333 }
  length: 2
```

My failing result (object of objects) yealds this:

```
{1: {…}, 2: {…}}
  1: {id: 1, name: "First", description: "some stuff", value: 222 }
  3: {id: 3, name: "Third", description: "Foo", value: 333 }
```

So `complexData.configs` is appearing to Javascript / Webix as a single object rather than a collection of objects.

So my question is this:

How can I reference `complexData.configs` in such a way that Javsacript / Webix knows it's a collection / or as an array?

or

Is there a way to get (mapping?) Webix to parse `complexData.configs` so that it recognizes the objects within as datatable rows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a rather simple solution to be found in [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```js
const complexData = {
  "configs": {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "First",
      "description": "some stuff",
      "value": 222
    },
    "3": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Third",
      "description": "Foo",
      "value": 333
    }
  }
}

console.info(Object.values(complexData.configs))
```

This isn't supported in any version of Internet Explorer however there are several [polyfills](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values#Polyfill) available

Comment: Super simple... Thanks.  How's Edge support on this?

Comment: [This says full Edge support since version 14](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values#Browser_compatibility)